# How do I send string from code behind in C# to Ajax JQuery and how do I parse it?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to know how to send a string from  asp.net to jQuery.

This is the code for ASP.NET and jQuery:

```
var jQueryXMLHttpRequest; 

$(document).ready(function () {

readNamesSent();
});

//Method         readNamesSent
//Parameters    : string
//Retrun        :  
//Description   : This file reads the name being sent from the StartingPage.aspx
function readNamesSent() {

jQueryXMLHttpRequest=$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "StartingPage.aspx/sendString",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response + "hi";
      
    },
    fail: function (response) {
       
    }
});
}
```

Below is the ASP.NET file code. The string that I am trying to send over to jQuery is the "name2".

The main problem we are having is trying to send the value and establishing a connection. jQuery to me is quite confusing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public partial class StartingPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // name in a string array over to jQuery
    public void openFile()
    {
        //  string LoadFile = "";
        //Store the file name 
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string fileStatus;
        string[] fileNameListToBeSent;

        string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MyFiles");
        
        string filepath2 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(""); 

        filepath2 = filepath2+@"\" + "MyFiles";

        bool tof = Directory.Exists(filepath2);
       
        fileNameListToBeSent = list.ToArray();
        string name2 = string.Join("|", fileNameListToBeSent);
        sendString(name2);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static new string sendString(string names)
    {
        string returnData;
        returnData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { listOfName = names });
        return reutrnData;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never send a string from code behind. It works the other way around. the Client side code would call the web method, and it returns a value. You can't and don't pass somthign from code behind. The client side browser code can run your js routine called readNamessent can call the web method on the server called sendString. but the REVERSE does not work that way at all. Your codebehind NEVER calls that [webmthod] function, but the client side js code can call that [webmethod].

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into below URL and check if it suites your problem

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-AJAX-call-with-parameters-example-Send-parameters-to-WebMethod-in-jQuery-AJAX-POST-call.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below sample

```
**Code**
[WebMethod]
public static string SayHello(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
**HTML**
<button type="button" onclick="callAJAX()" >Say Hello</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callAJAX() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SayHello",
            data:"{name: 'richie'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```